# Xenserver an local Storage (Xenserver Broken)

Tags: storage, xenserver, local

my Xenserver 6.1 was broken and i was using local storage on this server.

now i want to recover the local storage with the usual adding methods i delete the whole disk, but i want to keep the datea on the disks.

can anybody please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

While you are reinstalling, do NOT select your local storage as a SR. You can then Add (rather than Create) the SR after you've installed.

Have a look at the Upgrade manual, it details how to Upgrade (reinstall) without loosing your SR.